# ELF containing NEON or VFP3 instructions?

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, neon

Is it possible to see if an ELF contains NEON instructions?

My use case is:

On a Beaglebone I want to use OpenCV with NEON extensions. The BeagleBone runs Ubuntu. I'm not sure if the binaries from repository are compiled with NEON extensions activated. In case that the extensions are not activated I have to compile OpenCV by myself.

Answer (score 3):

try `readelf -A` and check if you see something like

```
Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
```

Comment: Note; for binaries that contain use of NEON, but where it isn't mandatory (i.e. it's only activated at runtime after a check for the cpu feature), such flags are sometimes inhibited, to signal that the binaries are ok for use on devices without said extensions. (I remember that they used to check for such details in raspbian to make sure that binaries had been compiled the right way.)